# ion-searchbar to have cancel icon instead of cancel text ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I need to have cancel icon next to ion-searchbar. Now I have text as Cancel next to ion-searchbar. The text if provided by me and now I want to replace the text with image.

```
<ion-searchbar  name="doSearch" (search)="doSearch($event)" [(ngModel)]="searchFilter" [showCancelButton]="true" cancelButtonText="Cancel" placeholder="Search" (ionCancel)="searchCancel($event)" (ionInput)="onInput($event)" (ionBlur)="onInputBlur()" (ionFocus)="onInputFocus()" (ionClear)="onInputClear($event)" >
```

I tried to remove the cancel button and also tried getting the element and inserted the class name.

```
  var element = document.getElementById(".searchbar-ios .searchbar-ios-cancel .button-inner");
  element.classList.add("fa fa-angle-down fa-2x down-arrow");
```

It throws an error stating `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'element.classList')`

Can you let me know to to get Cancel icon instead of cancel text in ion-searchbar.

Comment: I'd rather set `showCancelButton` to false and place your own button next to the searchbar. Then you can register a click event on this button and do your cancel logic there...

Answer (score 0):

Remove `[showCancelButton]="true" cancelButtonText="Cancel"` from `ion-searchbar`. You will get remove icon button by default.